# How to load multiple pages at the same time on Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I have different Contentviews in my app. Each Contentview is displayed when I clicked on button.

My Problem:

I would like to load all my Contentview more quickly because it takes time.

My Question :

Is there a better way to load Contentviews and get more speed performance ?

At the moment, I use this function to load my pages when the app start in MainPage :

```
void InitializeMyViews()
{  
     var tasks = new List<Task>();

     tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
           // Children Page
            MyAddWordsView.Content = new MyAddWordPage().Content;
         });    
      }));

    
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
           // Children Page
            MyTestView.Content = new MyQuestionPage().Content;  
        });   
     }));


    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
           // Children Page
           MySettingView.Content = new LeafSetting().Content;
        });

     }));

    
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {

       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Children Page
            LeafCommunityView.Content = new LeafCommunity().Content;
        });

      }));

    
    Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: You would be better off finding out what exactly about each page takes most time. Details: Most of the time cost occurs when a page is first displayed. At this time, layout (positions and sizes) are computed, and native controls are created, to correspond to the Maui controls. AFAIK, there is no way to perform these actions “offline”. I mean, without any interference to the user interacting with your app. If you encounter a performance problem, I recommend isolating exactly what xaml and code causes the biggest delay. Then ask for help in optimizing that.

Comment: Also, before concluding performance is a problem, test without a debugger attached. And if testing for mobile, test on an actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using asynchronous programming, you can also reduce unnecessary bindings, use fast renderers, enable the XAML compiler ...

There are many ways to improve Xamarin.Forms App Performance. You can check this
[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance).